# PTIJ: corona is good?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I heard some people singing a Purim song recently. At least, I think it was a Purim song: I couldn't make out all the words, but I'm pretty sure it mentioned Mordechai, Haman, and Esther. But at the end were these words:

> וגם קורונה זכור לטוב

Why are we mentioning corona as something *good*?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Well, the beer and the one around the sun and the one attached to us are all good...it's the virus that stinks.

Answer (score 6):

These people obviously wanted to express their gratitude after drinking a few Corona *beers*.

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I've been thinking.

Answer (score 5):

[Corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona,_Queens) is a neighborhood in Queens, NY, located close to the former World's Fair pavilions. Some of the pavilions still exist in Flushing Park, nearby. The neighborhood has been predominantly Dominican and Latino for decades. During the 1960's and 70's the crime rate in the neighborhood was very high.

Then, thankfully, one day, a nice Jewish boy named Paul Simon visited the neighborhood. He was well-known as a singer when he sang with his Jewish buddy Neil Garfunkel, so many in the neighborhood knew him, already. He played a game of basketball with a Peurto Rican boy named Julio. They became good friends and eventually, Paul Simon became Julio's mentor significantly changing his errant behavior.

Paul Simon, eventually wrote a song called "[Me and Julio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6VrKro8djw)" which has a line "Good Bye Rosie the Queen of Corona". (Rosie, it seems, was Julio's girlfriend.)

Since Paul Simon wrote this song not only did he transform Julio himself into a well-behaved boy, but the crime rate in the neighborhood declined, significantly. So, we see how much good a nice Jewish boy did to Corona. Thus, the song is, in a sense, an allusion to both Corona and Paul Simon.

Answer (score 2):

Corona (like influenza, etc.) is the מלאך המוות, and the מלאך המוות is טוב, as the Medrash ([Berashis Rabah 9:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.9.10?with=all&lang=bi)) says:

> והנה טוב מאוד זה מלאך המוות

(This answer, BTW, is not Purim Torah. It just has to be understood. See the rest of the Medrash.)